# Sort seguido de map não funcionando no React

Tags: javascript, react

Eu tenho um array de objetos e estou tentando iterar com o `map` nesse array após o metodo de `sort`, porém ele está fazendo a iteração no array normal, desconsiderando o metodo `sort` e a reordenação.

```
{this.mapasVetados
    .sort((a,b) => {
        return a.ordem - b.ordem
    })
    .map(mapa => {
        if (mapa.vetado) {
            return (<Vetados
                         mapa = {mapa.nome}
                         ordem = {mapa.ordem}
                    />)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Tem como criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do problema.

Comment: Acredito que não, o método é esse mesmo não sei como faria pra simplificar mais ainda. o map funciona, mas itera fora de ordem, então eu to fazendo algo errado no .sort

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema!

Nem todos os objetos que estavam sendo ordenados tinham a propriedade ordem, dai o sort "bugava" e não alterava o array. Adicionando um valor (0) em todos, funcionou